# Error while deploy Mule in jboss 4

Tags: mule

i have transformed my mule project into war file manually as mentioned in [mule to war](http://somaniab.blogspot.in/2012/12/steps-to-deploy-mule-esb-application-on.html) ,and i have change the web.xml appropriately and http endpoints with servlet endpoints, but when deploy that war, i got issues in jboss 4.

> 2013-02-21 13:35:47,236 DEBUG [org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener] Mule config file(s): sampleBkg.xml
>   2013-02-21 13:35:47,236 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/sampleBkg-war]] org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Note: my mule-config xml name is sampleBkg.xml and i have mentioned in web.xml file too.

another exception followed by first one.

> 2013-02-21 13:49:25,497 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/sampleBkg-war]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the commons-lang and mule-module-builders JARs in your web-app WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: ,hi, as u told, i tried with "mule-module-builders-3.3.0.jar", "commons-lang3-3.1.jar" in WEB_INF/lib, but still the error is occurring.i even tried with restart after deployment in Jboss. What would be the prob

Comment: Still the same exceptions?

Comment: Doesn't make sense unless you use classloader filtering. Do you need to deploy on JBoss? Could you deploy on Tomcat instead? That'll be way simpler (less classloading mess to deal with).

Comment: tried with Tomcat too, but got "ERROR listenerStart" error, It has all lib files but why its still throwing the same error in JBoss, but my primary target is to deploy with Jboss 4. Could u assist to achieve that.

Comment: Mule works just fine on Tomcat so there's probably an issue with the war you're building. On top of that, this issue is probably compounded with other issues on JBoss due to its _particular_ classloader. So I can't really assist you with in a forum like here.

Comment: for ur kind information, In Tomcat i have used the war file which is been deployed in Mule standalone server, there it deployed well, but the problem i faced with Mule standalone server is "i couldn't communicate with my project" since its endpoint is servlet.

Comment: That's great info, so it's really a classloading issue IMO. You need to use your JBoss classloader-fu to configure it so Mule works fine. I know some people have done that and it was no small feat apparently.

Comment: Thanks.. i couldn't find any config file like "classloader-fu".. where it will be in jboss ? what changes need to be done in that? pls explain

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Inside_the_JBoss_Class_Loading_Architecture-The_Complete_Class_Loading_Model.html and http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch2.chapter.html#d0e2314 - If you use JBoss you need to understand and be able to tweak it hierarchical classloader.

Comment: @Abhishek somani, hi am having that dependent jars in my project web-inf/lib folder itself, but it still throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

[Difference between classnotFoundExcption and noCLassDefFound Error](http://somaniab.blogspot.in/2013/02/classnotfoundexception-vs.html)
as the error says it is NoClassDefFoundError , which means that this class is in classpath , but it is dependent on some other classes which are not part of this jar ..try to find out dependency of commons lang jar .